# Creating a simple website grid with sidebar

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I'd like to create a responsive (or adaptive) site based on the [wireframes here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/753vqud9ge2zh37/AACwZXr5EU_WdOcwveb32ZO7a?dl=0) (also below). Essentially a 12 column grid with the first 1-2 filled with images and text in certain vertical areas.

How could I go about this? My thinking so far has been to create a dedicated left column, and then push everything else to the right of it. I feel as if this isn't semantic though, and am being forced to manually space items with absolute values.

The grid should work at both large (desktop) and small (mobile) sizes. Thanks for your help.

[image: Desktop example]
[image: Mobile example]

Comment: Posting some code you've tried would help you get more helpful answers. Check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for mobile-first adaptive frameworks.

Comment: There are a million grid-based frameworks out there...  start with that.